# backspace text field flutter on Android devices not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

when I do backspacing on a text, and then type again, the typing does not show up in the text field and the backspacing itself doesn't work good. I don't know if the problem is with the flutter itself or what because many people have the same issue.

```
                TextField(
                  controller: controller,
                  maxLength: 9,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,

                  onChanged: (text) {
                    if (7 > pin.length) {
                      final String newText = _addDashes(text);
                      controller.text = newText;
                      controller.selection =
                          TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length);
                    }

                    pin = text;
                  },
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  // keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    errorText: _errorText,
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.dialpad,
                    ),
                    labelText: '8-digit PIN',
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 2),
                    ),
                    focusedErrorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                    ),
                    errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFF696969), width: 1),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: facing this issue only if we assign value to controller in onChanged event

Comment: Can you add the entire widget to your snippet? For example, what are your `controller`, `pin`, and `_addDashes`? I suspect the issue comes from your `onChanged` method. So we need to know and understand everything you are doing in it.

Comment: To answer on your question you should provide `_addDashes` method content because every time when text is changed `onChanged` method calls again

Answer (score 1):

You can change your callback position from **OnChnage** to custom listener on controller. E.g.

```
controller.addListener(() {
    if (7 > pin.length) {
        final String newText = _addDashes(controller.text);
        controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(enter code here
        text: newText,
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length));
         }
    
    });
```

OR You can use same onChange Callback but use custom delayed as follows.

```
 onChanged: (text) {
     if (7 > pin.length) {
         final String newText = _addDashes(text);
     Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
    controller.text = newText;
    controller.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset:newText.length);
    
    });
      }       
       pin = text;
  
    }
```

USING FUTURE DELAYD IN ONCHANGE WORKING FOR ME

Comment: Future.delayed() works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me before and as per research, I found out that using `controller` and `onChanged` properties at the same time in a textField is what caused this error. I just can't find the doc where I read it but if I remember correctly, if you use `controller`, don't use `onChanged` or 'initialValue' and if some reason you need to use the `onChanged` or `initialValue` property, then the controller should be null.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Flutter TextEditingController documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html), you should use a `TextInputFormatter` instead of editing the value of the `TextEditingController` using a listener; the issue is similar to that caused by the `onChanged` callback:

> Gboard, for example, will try to restore the composing region of the text if it was modified programmatically, creating an infinite loop of communications between the framework and the input method.

A `TextInputFormatter` is one way to solve the issue. Others are moving the callback to `onSubmitted` or to a method that checks whether or not the widget has focus first.

Answer (score -1):

[Mask Text Input Formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter)

- Create Formatter

> var maskFormatter = MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: '####-####', filter:
> {"#": RegExp(r'[0-9]')}, type: MaskAutoCompletionType.eager);

- And add your TextField formatters

  ```
  TextField(
                  controller: controller,
                  maxLength: 9,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
                  // here -> 
                  inputFormatters: [maskFormatter],
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  // keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    errorText: _errorText,
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.dialpad,
                    ),
                    labelText: '8-digit PIN',
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 2),
                    ),
                    focusedErrorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                    ),
                    errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFF696969), width: 1),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
  ```
- Finally get the data

> ```
> maskFormatter.getMaskedText();
>
> maskFormatter.getUnmaskedText();
> ```

Comment: An irrelevant answer?
A textfield is designed and a formatter is created in the onChanged function and it works incorrectly, and it does not share some functions.
He asks if the error he created is due to Flutter or himself.
Then I'll answer for yourself.


I offered a simpler solution because you got an error.